# c# wrapper for c++ library,char array to stype*

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wrapper

i have a c++ library and i wanted to write a wrapper in c# for a function in the library.Function returns string  from library and i convert it char array in wrapper and function in the wrapper returns a char * to UI Form ,data that comes from wrapper converted to a sbyte* in the UI Form.I try to convert it to string in UI like this:

```
//i am giving values from a textbox
//and i am calling Function from wrapper
sbyte * data=c++library.class.function(double parameter1,double parameter2);
string result = new string.Empty;
while(*data!='\0'){
      result +=(char)(*data);
      ++data;
}
// and i try to show string in a textbox when i click a button,
textbox.Text=result;
```

but when i click the button,if i wait to see "12345" in textbox,i am seeing "&%**>" likee this unicode charecters,and if i continue to click button,string is changing,most times i can see right data but,continue to click it changes and showing unicode characters.

Can u help me abot How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Note that sbyte in C# is **not** equivalent to Char. If your "unmanaged" string is utf16 then your code is broken (and pretty inefficient). I'd do it on managed wrapper or better check a system.text.encoding

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Platform Invoke, and let it marshal the string.

Comment: i am doing this in Visual Studio 2010,is it possible to let it marshal the string in Visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to write the p/invoke code yourself. Though I have some code that does exactly what you need, since it is untested, I would rather refer you to a published article that has received good marks from peers.

Check out "Advanced Topics in PInvoke String Marshaling," at  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138614/Advanced-Topics-in-PInvoke-String-Marshaling,